# Key types supported by Redis

Tags: redis

What are the different key types supported by Redis? The documentation mentions all the various types (strings, set, hashmap, etc) of values supported by Redis, but I couldn't quiet find the key type information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keys in Redis are all strings, so it doesn't really matter what kind of value you pass into a client. Under-the-hood the RESP protocol is used and it will pass the value as a string to the engine.

Example:

```
ZADD some_key 1 some_value
```

`some_key` is always a string, even if you pass `3` as key, it is handled as a string. This is true for every client.

Answer (score 14):

From redis documentation ([Data types intro](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro)):

> **Redis keys**
>
> Redis keys are binary safe, this means that you can use any binary sequence as a key, from a string like "foo" to the content
>   of a JPEG file. The empty string is also a valid key. A few other
>   rules about keys:
>
> - Very long keys are not a good idea. For instance a key of 1024 bytes    is a bad idea not only memory-wise, but also because the
>     lookup of    the key in the dataset may require several costly
>     key-comparisons.    Even when the task at hand is to match the
>     existence of a large    value, hashing it (for example with SHA1) is a
>     better idea,    especially from the perspective of memory and
>     bandwidth.
> - Very short keys are often not a good idea. There is little point in    writing "u1000flw" as a key if you can instead write
>     "user:1000:followers". The latter is more readable and the added
>     space is minor compared to the space used by the key object itself
>     and the value object. While short keys will obviously consume a bit
>     less memory, your job is to find the right balance.
> - Try to stick with a schema. For instance "object-type:id" is a good    idea, as in "user:1000". Dots or dashes are often used for multi-word 
>     fields, as in "comment:1234:reply.to" or "comment:1234:reply-to".
> - The maximum allowed key size is 512 MB.

From my experience `any binary sequence` typically means a `String`, but I may not be familiar with languages where you can achieve this by using other data types.